# How to protect the circuit from Ethernet ESD, overvoltage, etc

Tags: opto-isolator, ethernet, protection

Creating a carrier board for a RPI Compute Module4, I am not sure how to protect the circuitry from possible ESD /over-voltage coming through Ethernet connector.

In normal circumstances, I would apply some zener diode and in-serie resistors, but I don't think this will work with a 1Gbps Ethernet (response time, impedance, etc).

I also looked for optocouplers IC, but all what I seen works only up to few MHz.

Looking at the Development board, it has a couple of IC protecting the input, unfortunately, no label for this 2.5mm IC:

[image]

**Is there any "standard" IC to protect the board from Ethernet? I am not necessarily looking for a specific part number, but rather a IC type name or family.**

Comment: Are you looking for protection before or after the magnetics, i.e. PHY side or connector side? Note that a magjack has integrated magnetics. Also, you can't use optocouplers at all, unless you mean MII/RMII, and you still need isolated supply for PHY. And that Ethernet interface is already isolated (the data is, but not necessarily the connector shell).

Comment: What does the ethernet connector carry? Is it ethernet or a signal with DC in it?

Comment: Good question, I had no idea of those "magnetics", I will read about them. I expect to put this protection between the female Ethernet (RJ45) connector and the Compute Module (IC processor). Exactly like the the Development board does.

Comment: It really carry Ethernet High-speed (1Gbps) data. TCP/IP 5 layers.

Comment: The mag jack is most of what you need for isolation. Note *most*.

Comment: @AdrianMaire Well you must first figure out what kind of interface the Raspi provides to you and how you must interface it. If you want to do it like the original IO board, then copy the original IO board. Schematics and part numbers for the Ethernet is available.

Comment: Why do you think that ethernet uses magnetics? The clue's in the name.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. You know, when one has no idea of something, it can be quite obscure until someone else ask the correct questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fast transients and ESD protection, zener will not be a proper solution.

As you mentioned, how fast signal is a problem also.

Transient suppression diodes (TVS) and ESD diodes could be used as such protections.

In such fast data lines, low capacitance diodes must be selected.

Many producers has their own manuals for specific application areas like gigabit ethernet, video interfaces etc.

https://www.littelfuse.com/technical-resources_old/application-designs/circuits/ethernet-esd-protection.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The full design files for the official Rpi compute module IO board are available so if you want to clone it then do so. It includes ESD protection for Ethernet.